# Sensu Handler Gives Undefined Method Error

Tags: sensu

We've recently updated our OpsGenie handler (`opsgenie.rb`) to the current community version, found [here](https://github.com/sensu/sensu-community-plugins/blob/master/handlers/notification/opsgenie.rb).

Our handler is defined as:

```
"opsgenie-pager" : {
  "type": "pipe",
  "command": "/etc/sensu/handlers/opsgenie.rb -j opsgenie-pager"
}
```

And our json config for `opsgenie-pager` is:

```
{
  "opsgenie-pager": {
  "customerKey": "<Our API Key>",
  "recipients": "<Our Schedule>,<Our Escalation>",
  "source": "Admiral Ackbar",
  "overwrite_quiet_hours": false,
  "tags": [ "admAckbar", "live", "pager" ]
  }
}
```

When a check returns as 'CRITICAL' and the `opsgenie` handler is called, the sensu-server.log reports:

```
{"timestamp":"2015-02-03T06:16:17.804061-0700","level":"info","message":"handler output","handler":{"type":"pipe","command":"/etc/sensu/handlers/opsgenie.rb -j opsgenie-pager","name":"opsgenie-pager"},"output":"/etc/sensu/handlers/opsgenie.rb:15:in `<class:Opsgenie>': undefined method `option' for Opsgenie:Class (NoMethodError)\n"}
{"timestamp":"2015-02-03T06:16:17.804210-0700","level":"info","message":"handler output","handler":{"type":"pipe","command":"/etc/sensu/handlers/opsgenie.rb -j opsgenie-pager","name":"opsgenie-pager"},"output":"\tfrom /etc/sensu/handlers/opsgenie.rb:13:in `<main>'\n"}
```

In our "dev instance" (vagrant box), we're able to successfully use the OpsGenie handler to create alerts.

Any ideas what would be causing the `undefined method 'option' for Opsgenie:Class (NoMethodError)` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this was the result of an outdated gem.

Out of chance I checked the installed packages (rpms and gems) between our "dev instance" and "production".

The `sensu-pluign` gem in our dev instance (installed during a `vagrant up`) was the current version (1.1.0) whereas the version installed on Production was an older version (0.6.3).

Updating this gem with

```
gem update sensu-plugin
```

solved this issue!